# Elasticsearch counts of multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a report to compare actual count from database with indexed records.

I have three indices index1, index2 and index3

To get the count for a single index i am using the following URL

```
http://localhost:9200/index1/_count?q=_type:invoice

=> {"count":50,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}
```

For multiple indices:

```
http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/_count?q=_type:invoice

=> {"count":80,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}
```

Now the count is added up, i want it to grouped by index also how can i pass filters group by a specific field
to get the output like this:

```
{"index1_count":50,"index2_count":50,"approved":10,"rejected":40 ,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `_search?search_type=count` and do an aggregation based on `_index` field to make the distinction between the indices:

```
GET /index1,index2/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the result would be something like this:

```
"aggregations": {
      "by_index": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "index1",
               "doc_count": 50
            },
            {
               "key": "index2",
               "doc_count": 80
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn’t work anymore, but [there’s a solution](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/no-search-type-for-count/101994/2): replace `?search_type=count` with `?size=0`.