# Elasticsearch - count per index for one query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

In an Elasticsearch cluster I have about 30 indices with the same structure.

I need to find out which of the indices would return at least 1 result for my query.

The result itself does not matter. I will make the business logic decisions based on the name of the index, that contains at least 1 document that satisfies the search criteria.

The search might return from 0 up to ~10 000 000 hits over all indices depending on the input. The search will be performed ~50 000 times with the different input.

I see the following solutions:

1. Use the search API with scrolling and look at all results to find out from which index they are.
   This is what is currently implemented and I'm looking for a faster solution.
2. Use the count API and do a count for every index. This will lead to more requests. *Might this be faster?*
3. Is there another possibility/API available?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472008/elasticsearch-counts-of-multiple-indices

Comment: and try with `_search?size=0` instead of `search_type=count`

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Thanks for the link. Could not find it before.

Comment: welcome sir. No Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `terms` bucket aggregation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) over the `_index` metadata field. Then, I would know what index has more than 1 hit.

E.g.,

```
{
  "query": { your_query },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": "30"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just had to add the size of indices that I query. Otherwise I did miss some indices.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the aggs like @glenacota mentioned. In addition, you can run that over multiple indices or against an `alias` pointing to all your 30 indices like

```
GET my_index_1, another_index_*/_search?size=0
```

Though,  I will also recommend to profile the query and see how it would fare against your cluster considering that you are looking at large number of indices, their document count and # of requests.